# ostream does not display proberly c++

Tags: c++, overloading, ostream, display

I have a project in which I use a Directory of people.  In my main class, I call cout << myDirectory << endl; to display the entire list of people in this directory.  To do so, I overwrite the << operator in both the Directory Class and Person class.

In the Directory class I use a Map for specific reasons so I display each person this way :

```
 std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const T& myDirectory)
{
  typedef map<Person, Location>::const_iterator Iterator;
  for(Iterator it=myDirectory.m_directory.begin();it!=myDirectory.m_directory.end;++it){
      os<<it->first<<endl;
}
return os;
```

In order to do so, I have to overload the << operator in the Person class also this way :

```
ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Person& p){
    os << p.lastName << "," << p.firstName << endl;
    return os;
}
```

My problem is that it is not displayed properly.  The comma goes before the last name and the last name and first name and kind of merged together.  For example, if my name is Jack Daniels, I would get this in output :

> ,Jackls

If I use endl; after last name and first name it works well.  For example :

```
os << p.lastName << endl;
os << "," << p.firstName << endl;
```

I get this output :

> Daniels
>   ,Jack

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I think your problem is with how you are reading in and storing the information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guessing here, because you haven't provided a complete example to show the problem, but I think you will have a trailing 'return' character at the end of the lastname.

It outputs "Daniels" and moves the cursor back to the beginning of the line, then overwrites that with ",Jack", so the output would be ",Jackls"

Comment: You got this ! I was reading from a file and each line had \r added at the end.  Did not realised but it was confusing the ostream I guess.  When creating my variables, I just have to remove the last character and then it works like charm.  Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score -1):

Endl also cleans the buffer. Maybe you should add out.flush() instead of endl and it will work then? Just guessing.

Comment: `endl` also does a `flush`.